# HtmlControl changing class

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
<div ID="btnWebL" runat="server" class="left_selected"></div>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="btnWeb" runat="server" CssClass="center_selected" OnClick="btnWeb_Click"
                    Text="<%$ Resources:ViaMura.Web.Default, WebSearchButtonText %>"></asp:LinkButton>
                <div ID="btnWebR" runat="server" class="right_selected"></div>
```

i want to change btnWeb class to left_not_selected.

I try with:

```
HtmlControl btnWebL = FindControl("btnWebL") as HtmlControl;
```

but btnWebL does not have property for changing class. How can i change class?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should be able to set the `class` attribute like so:

```
bntWebL.Attributes["class"] = "your_new_class";
```

See the [documentation here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlcontrol.attributes%28v=VS.80%29.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Try this code

```
HtmlControl btnWebL = FindControl("btnWebL") as HtmlControl;
bntWebL.Attributes["class"] = "left_not_selected";
```

I hope this will work for you.